# "You are no king" vs "You are not a king"

Tags: adjectives, no-not

I watched a movie, the character said

> You are no king.

I am thinking, why not say

> You are not king,
> You are not a king.

What's the difference?

Comment: In that sort of sentence any of the versions (and several others) may be used.  The usage chosen depends on the emotion and (likely) anger being expressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*He's no king* means that he does not look or act like a king (or lacks qualities typical of kings), but may in fact have the position of king; while *He's not a king* would typically imply that he does not hold the position of king, nothing more.

> [*He isn't a doctor*] simply says that he isn’t a member of the class of doctors, while [*He's no doctor*] says that he doesn’t have the
> properties of a doctor. Similarly, *He’s no friend of mine* implies that
> I know him and that his behaviour to me is not what one would expect
> of a friend, while *He’s not a friend of mine* says only that he doesn’t
> belong to the class of friends of mine – it could be that I hardly
> know him, or indeed that I don’t know him at all. (The Cambridge
> Grammar of the English Language p390)

Comment: But you can certainly say _He's no king_ when he is not a king. Using _no_ is simply being emphatic. The rationale behind the emphasis entirely depends on context.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion "you are not [a] king" merely denies kingship, something that can be rectified by an external act such as a coronation. The "a king" variant is arguably the more dismissive of the two.

"You are no king" is a negation of "[you are king](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/104200/24861)", where the lack of an article before "king" is understood as a null-article. It references an intrinsic quality (kingliness) regardless of external factors such as a valid coronation.

If someone had been crowned king but consistently acted in a manner unbefitting of a king, "you are not [a] king" would be an invalid assertion, while "you are no king" might be justifiable.

Answer (score 0):

*No* can be used as an adjective. As suggested in the [M-W dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no#dictionary-entry-2)—pay attention to entry 2 in the adjective section—*no* as an adjective can mean "not a; quite other than a." The example given in that definition

> He's no expert

is similar to your sentence "You are no king."

And so, your sentence basically means that "you" are **not a king**, or **quite other than a king**.

As for your other 2 sentences

> You are not king.

> You are not a king.

These sentences lack the emphasis in the word *no* that describes "you" as something quite other than a king, but just simply negate their position as a king.

And as for the difference between *king* and *a king*, *king* is more specific than *a king*. Using *a king* can just mean that "you" are not any king, but using *king* could be referring to a specific king position. See these examples:

> Louis XIX was not *a king*. (He did not become king at all)

> Louis XIV was not *king* of England. (He may not have been that king, but he was king of France.)

Comment: Wouldn't "Louis XIV was not a king of England" mean that he may not have been that king, but he was king of France? In that case, what difference does the article make?

Comment: I'd say "was not a king of England" only states the fact without giving further connotation, but "was not king of England," without the article, has a connotation that he was something else. Either way, it'd depend on the context.

Comment: I agree that there's a subtle difference between them. I think that your answer would benefit from poining that out, because the question only asks about including or excluding "a" whereas your example also changes "of England".